# Spark Streaming using Scala to insert to Hbase Issue

Tags: scala, stream, apache-spark

I am trying to read records from Kafka message and put into Hbase. Though the scala script is running with out any issue, the inserts are not happening. Please help me.

Input:
rowkey1,1
rowkey2,2

Here is the code which I am using:

```
object Blaher {
  def blah(row: Array[String]) { 
    val hConf = new HBaseConfiguration() 
    val hTable = new HTable(hConf, "test") 
    val thePut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row(0))) 
    thePut.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("a"), Bytes.toBytes(row(1))) 
    hTable.put(thePut) 
  } 
}


object TheMain extends Serializable{
  def run() {
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1)) 
    val topicmap = Map("test" -> 1)
    val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,"127.0.0.1:2181", "test-consumer-group",topicmap).map(_._2)
    val words = lines.map(line => line.split(",")).map(line => (line(0),line(1)))
    val store = words.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreach(Blaher.blah)) 
    ssc.start()
  } 
}

TheMain.run()
```

Comment: how many cores have you assigned to Spark when you create the SparkContext? (sc) ?

Comment: It looks like the issue is converting a rdd to an array. Somehome foreach rdd the call to Blaher.blah method is not happening properly. Is there anyway to pass the records as an array and get them inserted to hbase?

Answer (score 0):

From the API doc for `HTable`'s `flushCommits()` method: "Executes all the buffered Put operations". You should call this at the end of your `blah()` method -- it looks like they're currently being buffered but never executed or executed at some random time.